# Jenkins - Launch Method "Launch slave agents via SSH" missing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to connect to a Jenkins slave via SSH.

So I installed *"SSH Agent Plugin 1.15"* and *"SSH Slaves plugin 1.26"*, added SSH credentials (using a private key), but no "Launch Slave agents via SSH" is shown within the *Launch Method* dropdown of the node configuration dialog.

What am I doing wrong?

I use Jenkins 2.129, and I am sure that the entry was available in the dropdown a few releases before ...

I found an exception in the logs:

```
WARNING: Failed to instantiate
Key[type=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$DescriptorImpl, annotation=[none]]; skipping this component
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/tools/JDKInstaller$FileSystem
  at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$DescriptorImpl.<init>(SSHLauncher.java:1617)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1.get(ExtensionFinder.java:432)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder._find(ExtensionFinder.java:394)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder.find(ExtensionFinder.java:385)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:493)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:380)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:318)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:183)
    at hudson.DescriptorExtensionList.load(DescriptorExtensionList.java:192)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:318)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:172)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xunit.AliasInitializer.init(AliasInitializer.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1068)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/tools/JDKInstaller$FileSystem
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.<init>(Descriptor.java:289)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$DescriptorImpl.<init>(SSHLauncher.java:1617)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$DescriptorImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$7821d6d6.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.tools.JDKInstaller$FileSystem
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1374)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1327)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1080)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception I found *[NoClassDefFoundError "hudson/tools/JDKInstaller$FileSystem" at SSHLauncher after Jenkins Update 2.111->2.112](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50272)* (50272).

Here it is mentioned that I was missing the *[JDK-Tools Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jdk-tool)*.

Comment: Warning: This is a hack workaround plugin, unsuitable for production use.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when setting up a Node/Agent in Jenkins. I was unable to find the **Launch Agent via SSH** option in the **Launch Method**.

All I had to do was to install the **[SSH Build Agents plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-slaves/)** via the **Jenkins Update Center** (Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins).